# Command to see my current ip if proxy is applied only for a certain website

Tags: networking, bash, proxy

It might not be a relevent question here on so, but I tried on http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com and there are less users + they redirected me here.

So, I am not a networking guy and I have the next situation:
- I have a browser addon / plugin (a public one - it is called proxmate )
- This is routing the traffic through a supported proxy server regardless of what country the user is in. It also lets the user to set up his own proxy servers (didn’t actually find this feature) to automatically get around any country-specific blocks he might run into.
- My problem is that I want to verify on multiple virtual machines the proxy that they use in order to make some research about this concept. It might seem pretty easy, but it is not, as they are using a package for every website so that the IP changes only when that site is accessed.

Any ways to see what proxy they use in,lets say, 3 different sessions ?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 so I would like any solution to be based on this distro. I've tried live HTTP Headers and Tamper data but none fit my needs

Comment: it is not enough for example, from the browser of each virtual machine to [ask for "which is my ip" in Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=which+is+my+ip) or in [site like whatismyip.com](https://www.whatismyip.com/)?

Comment: Your solution will return my original IP address. The IP changes only for a specific website ( for a website that I have that package installed). That's all. And that's why I want to retrieve / see that proxy

Comment: Please add some line about what  you have just tried. BTW anything interesting from `netstat ` maybe with `-vatnee` or if supported `-M`?  Moreover from   `cat`+ `/proc/net/route`, `/proc/net/ip_masquerade`, `/proc/net/tcp`... You can try to see if there is some direct traffic to the targeted sites...